# ebay apis php error undefined index

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

I'm implementing a vary simple search engine to ebay items  using eBay APIs for a university project.
I have a simple index.php file containing a search box :

```
<form action="MySample1.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="query" size="90" maxlength="255" />
    <input type="submit" value="Cerca" /> 
</FORM>
```

and a sample.php file for displaying the results. The sample.php file implements a function findItemsByKeywordsResults just as following:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);  // Turn on all errors, warnings and notices for easier debugging

// API request variables
$endpoint = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';  // URL to call
$s_endpoint = "http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?";  // Shopping URL to call
$m_endpoint = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/MerchandisingService?';  // Merchandising URL to call
$version = '1.0.0';  // API version supported
$appid = 'ed-7877-4e90-a4b4-bc6d897f71c3';  // Generated via My Account to ebay developer
$globalid = 'EBAY-US';  // Global ID of the eBay site you want to search (e.g., EBAY-DE)
$responseEncoding = 'XML';  // Type of response we want back
$cellColor = "bgcolor=\"#dfefff\"";  // Light blue background used for selected items
$_SESSION['query'] = $_POST['query'];

function findItemsByKeywordsResults($selectedItemID = '', $cellColor = '') {
    $query= $_SESSION['query'];
    $safequery = urlencode( $query);  // Make the query URL-friendly
    global $endpoint;
    global $appid;
    global $responseEncoding;
    global $version;
    global $globalid;
    global $sort;

    $results = "<FORM ACTION=\"" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "\" METHOD=\"POST\"> \n";
    $results .= "<FIELDSET>\n<LEGEND>Sort by: </LEGEND>\n";
    $results .= "<SELECT NAME=\"Order\" onchange=\"this.form.submit();\"> \n";
    $results .= "<OPTION VALUE=\"BestMatch\" SELECTED=\"selected\"> Best Match </OPTION> \n";
    $results .= "<OPTION VALUE=\"BidCountFewest\" > Bid Count Ascending </OPTION>  \n";
    $results .= "<OPTION VALUE=\"BidCountMost\"> Bid Count Descending </OPTION>  \n";
    $results .= "<OPTION VALUE=\"PricePlusShippingLowest\" > Price + Shipping Ascending </OPTION>  \n";
    $results .= "<OPTION VALUE=\"PricePlusShippingHighest\"> Price + Shipping Descending </OPTION>  \n";
    $results .= "</SELECT> \n </FIELDSET> \n";
    $results .= "</FORM> \n";  

    // Construct the findItemsByKeywords HTTP GET call
    $apicall = "$endpoint?";
    $apicall .= "OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords";
    $apicall .= "&SERVICE-VERSION=$version";
    $apicall .= "&SECURITY-APPNAME=$appid";
    $apicall .= "&GLOBAL-ID=$globalid";
    $apicall .= "&sortOrder=$sort";
    $apicall .= "&keywords=$safequery";
    $apicall .= "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=10";

    // Load the call and capture the document returned by eBay API
    $resp = simplexml_load_file($apicall);

    // Check to see if the request was successful, else print an error
    if ($resp->ack == "Success") {
        $results .= '';
        // If the response was loaded, parse it and build links

        $results .= "<h2>These are the results for  <i>". $_SESSION['Query'] ."</i> </h2>\n";
        $results .= "<!-- start table in findItemsByKeywordsResults --> \n";
        $results .= "<table width=\"60%\" cellpadding=\"5\" border=\"1\">";

        //for each item node build a table cell and append it to $results
        foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item){
            // Set the cell color blue for the selected most watched item
            if ($selectedItemID == $item->itemId) {
                $thisCellColor = $cellColor;
            } else {
                $thisCellColor = '';
            }

            // Determine which price to display
            if ($item->sellingStatus->currentPrice) {
                $price = $item->sellingStatus->currentPrice;
            } else {
                $price = $item->listingInfo->buyItNowPrice;
            }

            // For each item, create a cell with imageURL, viewItemURL, watchCount, currentPrice
            $results .= "<tr> \n<td $thisCellColor valign=\"top\"> \n";
            $results .= "<img src=\"$item->galleryURL\"></td> \n";
            $results .= "<td $thisCellColor valign=\"top\"> <p><a href=\"" . $item->viewItemURL . "\">" . $item->title . "</a></p>\n";
            $results .= 'Shipped to: <b>' . $item->shippingInfo->shipToLocations . "</b><br> \n";
            $results .= 'Current price: <b>$' . $price . "</b><br><br> \n";
            $results .= "<FORM ACTION=\"" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "\" METHOD=\"POST\"> \n";
            $results .= "<INPUT TYPE=\"hidden\" NAME=\"Selection\" VALUE=\"$item->itemId\"> \n";
            $results .= "<INPUT TYPE=\"submit\" NAME=\"$item->itemId\" ";
            $results .= "VALUE=\"Get Details and Similar Items\"> \n";
            $results .= "</FORM> \n";
            $results .= "</td> </tr> \n\n";
        }
        $results .= "</tr></table> \n<!-- finish table --> \n";
    }
    // If the response does not indicate 'Success,' print an error
    else {
        $results  = "<h3>Oops! The request was not successful. Make sure you are using a valid ";
        $results .= "AppID for the Production environment.</h3>";   
    }
    return $results;
}//end of the function
```

well, initially I obtain the right results. the problem come when i try to reorder the results using the Sort By form and reload the page. The error I find is :

Notice: Undefined index: query in C:\xampp\htdocs\GettingStarted\Sample.php on line 23

Can someone of you help me to solve this problem??

Comment: `$_POST['query'];` is not set, you are submitting the form without filling `query` field

Comment: Which line is line 23 in `C:\xampp\htdocs\GettingStarted\Sample.php on line 23`?

Comment: $_SESSION['query'] = $_POST['query']; is the line..

Comment: @user2092317 Post it as an answer.

Comment: @user2092317: if it isn't filled, `$_POST['query'];` is empty (`""`) and not undefined

Comment: check your form action is `MySample1.php` and you are showing `sample.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of the below code:

```
$_SESSION['query'] = $_POST['query'];
```

use the following code:

```
$_SESSION['query'] = isset($_POST['query']) ? $_POST['query'] : (isset($_SESSION['query']) ?$_SESSION['query'] : '' );
```

Comment: Error : Oops! The request was not successful. Make sure you are using a valid AppID for the Production environment.

Comment: @albinf this is the different problem you need to use the right value for the `$appid` variable.

Comment: yes but this is an error message that i have implemented in my code at line 66

Comment: @albinf which is line number 66?

Comment: else {
   $results  = "<h3>Oops! The request was not successful. Make sure you are using a valid ";
   $results .= "AppID for the Production environment.</h3>"; 
  }

Comment: really it's not line 66 i don't know why i confused it..its line 102

Comment: line 66 is not so relevant..i don't know why i wrote it for error..the right line is 102 : else { $results = "<h3>Oops! The request was not successful. Make sure you are using a valid "; $results .= "AppID for the Production environment.</h3>";  }

Comment: i don't know if i'm clear enough but since the problem comes when i reload the page for ordering the items i think i make an error in setting the $_SESSION variable but i dont know what i'm doing wrong..

Comment: @albinf check that what is the value of `$resp->ack` by echoing it. and try to use the exception to get the exact error. this is your custom message.

Comment: oh..i solved it..i just changed $_SESSION['query'] = isset($_POST['query']) ? $_POST['query'] : (isset($_SESSION['query']) ?$_SESSION['query'] : '' );  to  $_SESSION['query'] = isset($_POST['query']) ? $_POST['query'] : $_SESSION['query']; and it works...

Answer (score 0):

```
$_POST['query']; is not set, you are submitting the form without filling query
```

Comment: I'm sure i fill the query in index.php

Comment: check your form action is  `MySample1.php` and you are showing `sample.php`, please check

Comment: I'm running MySample1.php but I wrote sample.php just for making it seem better.lol